# Self signed certificate IIS7 - The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: web-services, iis-7, ssl, self-signed

I have a website hosted on my web server contacting a secure web service on another server. I have created a self signed certificate and attached it to the https:// binding. I have done 2 things to try and accept the certificate on my web server:

1. Open IE and browse to my wsdl file in the web service - Installed the certificate to the   Trusted Root Cert Authority.
2. Exported the certificate from the other server, gone into MMC and installed imported it manually into the Local Computer Trusted Root Cert Auth.

Neither of these have worked and I am not sure which route to try next.

System: Windows Server 2008 running IIS7.

Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do this the way everyone else seems to do it by overriding the certificate check. Not what I wanted but has sorted it for now.